# React native: Using a panResponder inside of a scrollview broken on android

Tags: android, react-native

I know this issue has been raised many times but I have not found a working fix on any of the other threads (Most of which have very little to no replies).

In my implementation I have a ScrollView which is a parent to a list of items that each have a panResponder for sideways swiping (Like tinder cards).

The issue I am having is that the ScrollView stops the panResponder mid-animation and prioritizes scrolling.

I have tried dynamically toggling `scrollEnabled` on the scrollView on `onPanResponderGrant` and `onPanResponderRelease` but this is not a viable solution since scrolling vertically on a panResponder triggers `onPanResponderGrant` disabling scrolling.

Here is my implementation of `panResponder`:

```
this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => false,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => false,
        onShouldBlockNativeResponder: (evt, gestureState) => false,
        onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => false,
        onPanResponderGrant: (event, gestureState) => {
          this.pan.setValue(0);
          this.opacity.setValue(0)
          this.rotation.setValue(0)
        },
        onPanResponderMove: (event, gesture) => {
            this.pan.setValue(gesture.dx)
            this.rotation.setValue(gesture.dx)
            this.opacity.setValue(gesture.dx)
          },  
        onPanResponderRelease: (event, gestureState) => {
            if(gestureState.dx < -SWIPE_THRESHOLD){
                this.removeCard()
              } else {
                this.resetPosition()
              }
        }
      });
```

And here is the FlatList that renders each swipable card:

```
 <FlatList
            data={this.state.cards}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <DataCard
              type={item.type}
              name={item.name}
              />
            )}
          />
```

I have since swapped out `ScrollView` with a `FlatList` with hopes of magically resolving this but no luck.

This functionality works flawlessly on iOS but the issue is still android.

It seems like this is a pretty common issue that has no concrete solution. Which is what Im hoping for by posting this.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, still facing this issue... Im surprised that there isn't any solution to be found.

Comment: You still haven't found a solution, have you?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's very late, but I hope this answer will help other people that like me had the same problem. 
**It looks like PanResponder doesn't support very well when two different parent components are trying to stop your animation** (in this case you have a FlatList inside a ScrollView)

The solution that worked for me is to **set the FlatList's scrollEnabled to false** (it will still work as you're inside another scroll view) This way the pan responder will have to deal just with the ScrollView

Also - don't forget to set "onPanResponderTerminate()" to let the component return to the initial position and give back scrollable=true to the parent component (ScrollView) like so:

```
  onPanResponderTerminate: () => {
    this.props.changeScrollable(true);
    this.resetPosition();
  },
```

I really hope this was clear enough and that will help someone!

Answer (score 1):

I struggle with this problem too, i don't know if is the best way but it's working for me (after a lot of wastes hours)

```
this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => false,
    onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => false,
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => false,
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => false,
    onShouldBlockNativeResponder: () => false,
    onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
        if (this.state.isPanAlive) {
            this.doSomething()
        }
        return false
    },
});
```

and i put is inside `ScrollView` because i got scrolling problem with `View`

```
<ScrollView {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (_, gestureState) => {
  return Math.abs(gestureState.dx) > 10;
},
```

This works because the **PanResponder** won't be given control until the delta is ~10 or so points. The value is arbitrary.

Comment: This is great, exactly what I needed. So many people overcomplicate it. You don't even need to manage the stop or start of the scrolling of the parent component (potentially causing re-renders all throughout the children). Well done!

Answer (score 1):

Use setNativeProps to control scrolling in onPanResponderStart

```
    onPanResponderStart: () => {
      scrollViewRef.setNativeProps({ scrollEnabled: false });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onShouldBlockNativeResponder: () => false` in the `PanResponder.create` config object

Comment: Yes, that is currently the configuration that I am using. Sill having the issue of the scroll blocking the panResponder

Answer (score 0):

```
onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => false
```

Setting this to false blocks the scrollview's request to override the gesture.